# Service not starting, but no errors are being generated to show why they're not starting

Tags: shell-script, kali-linux, services

OpenVAS has been quite a nightmare to get installed and running successfully and consistently on Kali. I understand there's a docker image for that and what not, but still.

The issue I'm facing is the `ospd-openvas` service is not starting when I run it manually, although it starts when I run `gvm-check-setup`, even though it's running the exact same `systemctl start ospd-openvas` command.

```
___(root__docker-desktop)-[~]
__# systemctl status ospd-openvas
ospd-openvas.service - OpenVAS Wrapper of the Greenbone Vulnerability Management (ospd-openvas)
    Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/ospd-openvas.service, disabled)
    Active: inactive (dead)

___(root__docker-desktop)-[~]
__# systemctl start ospd-openvas

___(root__docker-desktop)-[~]
__# systemctl status ospd-openvas
ospd-openvas.service - OpenVAS Wrapper of the Greenbone Vulnerability Management (ospd-openvas)
    Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/ospd-openvas.service, disabled)
    Active: inactive (dead)
```

but if I run it with `gvm-check-setup`, then it works fine:

```
Step 6: Checking Greenbone Security Assistant (GSA) ...
Oops, secure memory pool already initialized
        ERROR: Greenbone Security Assistant too old or too new: 21.4.1~dev1
        FIX: Please install Greenbone Security Assistant >= 21.04.
        OK: Greenbone Security Assistant is present in version 21.4.1~dev1.
Step 7: Checking if GVM services are up and running ...
        Starting ospd-openvas service
        Waiting for ospd-openvas service
        OK: ospd-openvas service is active.
        Starting gvmd service
        Waiting for gvmd service
        OK: gvmd service is active.
        Starting greenbone-security-assistant service
        Waiting for greenbone-security-assistant service
        OK: greenbone-security-assistant service is active.
Step 8: Checking few other requirements...
        OK: nmap is present in version 21.4.1~dev1.
        OK: ssh-keygen found, LSC credential generation for GNU/Linux targets is likely to work.
        WARNING: Could not find makensis binary, LSC credential package generation for Microsoft Windows targets will not work.
        SUGGEST: Install nsis.
        OK: xsltproc found.
        WARNING: Your password policy is empty.
        SUGGEST: Edit the /etc/gvm/pwpolicy.conf file to set a password policy.

It seems like your GVM-21.4.1 installation is OK.

___(root__docker-desktop)-[~]
__# systemctl status ospd-openvas
ospd-openvas.service - OpenVAS Wrapper of the Greenbone Vulnerability Management (ospd-openvas)
    Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/ospd-openvas.service, disabled)
    Active: active (running)
```

How do I actually troubleshoot why this service isn't being started when I try starting it? I've tailed the entire `/var/log/gvm/*` folder with `tail -f`, and it doesn't seem like nothing is being generate there. There is also nothing in `journalctl -xe` as it says "-- No entries --".

[image]

Comment: It looks like the ospd-openvas service is not actually enabled; have you tried enabling it?

Comment: I believe that's just disabled on startup. I actually was able to enable another service that showed the sames thing. I also figured out what the solution was to the issue I was having (needed to be in the root folder), but nevertheless I still don't understand why there isn't any error being produced here.